# How to copy (to clipboard) only significant part of a plot in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, clipboard

How to copy (to clipboard) only significant part of a plot in Matlab? Without that large gray margins Matlab loves so much?

Is it possible to populate clipboard from Matlab command line?

Comment: Here's a few links that may help, [Matlab Forum](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/62253) and [Undocumented Matlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/screencapture-utility/).

Comment: What do you mean by *"clipboard from Matlab command line"*?

Comment: @macduff: I was excited about `print -dmeta` until I discovered that it's Windows-only. Sad.

Answer (score 0):

As far as programmatically populating the system clipboard with image data captured from a Matlab figure goes, you might try Yair Altman's, [ScreenCatpture utility](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24323-ScreenCapture) on the Matlab File Exchange:

```
screencapture('handle',gca,'target','clipboard');
```

It has a lot of options and will allow you to specify a region or an entire figure. It does require Java, i.e., it won't run in '-nojvm' mode. You can read more about it at Yair's [Undocumented Matlab site](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/screencapture-utility/).

Also, you can change the current figure's background color to white before copying it via:

```
set(gcf,'Color','w');
```

Answer (score 0):

In the figure window, choose "edit" -> "Copy Figure".

It's equal to Ctrl+C on text, etc., but takes only the main part of the figure. So if you go to word, say, and press Ctrl+V, or RIght Click -> Paste, you will get only the main part of figure, without the gray margins you hate so much...